# Hard drive failure recovery

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

Yesterday my family's laptop's hdd gave out and stop working. When the computer is turned on it says `Checking Media [fail]`. After I go into the BIOS settings is says `Fixed HDD       <Not Detected>`. I then opened the laptop and removed the hdd. I removed the pcb from the hdd and looked at it. There were no burn marks or anything suspicious. I need help identifying the problem and finding a solution.

[image: Hard Drive Picture]

Comment: Its dead. There's almost nothing you can do if a hard drive isn't detected. You can't run checks, you can't recover. Basically you're out of luck. If it wasn't under warranty, you might have voided it, but sudden HDD death should be covered. Else, time to get a new hard drive.

Comment: I agree with JourneymanGeek, but you could try to slave it in a computer to see if anything can be retrieved ... Solution is to buy a new one

Comment: Ugh, ok... That's a bit frustrating that I can't get the data off of it

Comment: While searching for solutions, I found that one of the recommended solutions was to replace the pcb

Comment: That might work, if the computer can't recognize it then it is most likely the board

Comment: @jakebacker44 remember if you are going to replace the PCB, it should be an **identical** drive only, same part number, revision, and as close to the same manufacture date as possible... As an example I have seen a HD with a Rev A board go bad and you put a Rev B board on it and it won't work, or works but needs formatting to be readable which kind of ruins the whole idea of why it was done. Even so, this is still just a 50/50 shot at best.

Comment: You can recovery the data just a matter of how much your willing to spend in order to do so, which is the reason, backups are so important.

Answer (score 2):

There is also another small possibility. Maybe the sata controller fails for a reason. You can try to attach your HDD to another computer or to an external usb-to-sata converter.